# Объединить метки про хеширование

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

Надо объединить метки [хеширование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), [хеш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d0%b5%d1%88), [hash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hash) а также [хэширование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [хэш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d1%8d%d1%88) (через "э").

Как мне кажется, метка должна называться [хеширование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Answer (score 3):

Звучит разумно.

Выставил на голосование четыре синонима: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/хеширование/synonyms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/synonyms).